# I'd rather stay than go/to go/going home?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, verbs

Despite being reasonably fluent in English, I have no intuition for what's correct here:

> I'd rather stay than go home.
>
> I'd rather stay than to go home.
>
> I'd rather stay than going home.

All three sound natural to me. Could you explain which variants are actually correct and point me to the relevant grammar rules? If more than one are correct, could you also comment on the nuances between them?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's only logical to use the same form of "go" in the second part of the sentence as the form of "stay" in its first part. And this form of "stay" is forced by "would rather" (see e.g. http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/verb-patterns/would-rather-would-sooner). So the only correct, and natural sounding, version is the first one:

> I'd rather stay than go home.

Sentences with other forms of "go" can also be formed, but that would require changing the first part of the sentence. For example:

> I'd prefer staying here to going home.

Comment: Worth noting that the 'to' in your 2nd example is not the infinitive but the normal preposition in 'prefer X to Y' so the rule about matching the first verb still holds.

Comment: I like this concept of *the second verb takes the form of the first one*. It explains both sentences (the OP's one and the second in the answer)

Comment: But I think that "I'd rather go home than to stay" would be relatively commonly heard.

I think the function of the "to" for the second verb is to make for clarity and easier reading by giving the reader an extra syntax signal for the upcoming meaning.

Comment: @Ann: No, I don't think so. "I'd rather go home than to stay" is ungrammatical.

Comment: @zipirovich Nah. It's not ungrammatical. And it's common as well.

LOL! Does this mean we have reached an impasse?
So soon in the thread too!

Comment: "I want to go to school, not stay home."

Comment: Here are other examples of this common phrasing that does not use this kind of parallelism:
> I want to go shopping, not stay home.
> Sheila decided to make up with her sister, not hold a grudge.

Comment: @Ann: Sure, we might as well continue the thread. :-) Omitting something that has already appeared to avoid repetitiveness is indeed quite common. But it usually happens **after** the word has already appeared (so that we don't repeat it), not **before** (in which case it just logically doesn't make much sense). That's why `I want to go to school, not stay home` is fine, but `I'd rather go home than to stay` isn't.

Comment: @Ann: In `I want to go to school, not stay home` the verbs are in the same form, so parallelism is preserved; it's just that "to" is omitted to avoid repetition. In it we have two ideas -- "I want **to** go to school" and "I want **to** stay home", -- and we're saying that we prefer the former to the latter. But in `I'd rather go home than to stay`, the assumed second part when expanded would be "I'd rather to stay", which is ungrammatical.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than usually occurs between two things which are being compared. However, we can also use it at the beginning of a sentence. When we use rather than with a verb, we use the base form or (less commonly) the -ing form of a verb:

*Rather than **pay*** the taxi fare, he walked home.

or

*Rather than **paying*** the taxi fare, he walked home
-[Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/british-grammar/adverbs-of-degree/rather)